# Instructions for bridges do not match the browser tools

Tags: configuration, bridge, update, website, settings

There are a few places in the user manuals that talk about bridges. Three different methods of using bridges are mentioned, however, only one of them works. I have looked exhaustively and have been unable to find a 'Tor' option in the sidebar of the 'Preferences' page accessed through the hamburger menu, or anywhere else. I also have been unable to locate the Tor Browser's Network Settings, which is another way to get to create bridges that is mentioned. The only way to I have found so far to make a bridge is to access the network settings in the welcome screen where you unlock your persistent storage. Just thought you guys might want to be aware that this is the case, and that it's confusing for the user, so you can maybe get that updated. Links and text below. Keep up the good work, thank you!!!

http://dgvdmophvhunawds.onion/bridges/index.html

"Or, if you have Tor Browser running, click on "Preferences" in the hamburger menu and then on "Tor" in the sidebar. In the "Bridges" section, check the checkbox "Use a bridge," and from the option "Provide a bridge I know," enter each bridge address on a separate line. Your settings will automatically be saved once you close the tab."

http://qrmfuxwgyzk5jdjz.onion/docs/bridges.html.en

"2) To begin using bridges, open Tor Browser's Network Settings:"

Comment: Hi, what version of the Tor Browser are you using? The "Tor" appears in the sidebar for me: https://imgur.com/a/DVAY7GR.

Comment: Hello! I'm using 9.5, it just released this month. As far as I can tell it is the most up to date. What version are you using?

Comment: Also 9.5. So yours doesn't have the "Tor" button in the sidebar like in the picture? If so then this is definitely a bug.

Comment: Nope, my button is missing. I will reinstall and see what happens. I'm kind of glad, those tools looked cool and it didn't make much sense to me why they would have removed them in a newer version. Thanks for getting me straightened out!